# Comparison of data tables

Tags: tables, data, comparison

What is an effective pattern to allow users to compare two or more data tables with multiple (i.e 4) columns in each table?

For example, we have a table with 4 rows and 4 columns for geographic revenue across last 4 years for a company *ABC*, now I want to add another company to compare (or possibly multiple companies).

In this case, how do we show this second table to compare values with the original table?

It's easy when we have only one row or column but in this case, we have more than one rows and columns. Any example would be helpful!

Comment: Hi, tough to give an answer with so little information. What's the purpose? What's the data you're trying to compare? Who will use this?

Comment: You need to edit your original question rather than provide a comment.

Comment: can you provide wireframe or rough sketch? What are the fields you are going to include? Can it be club into one?

Comment: Does the data have to be shown in a table? If the data is value over time then you could show it as 4 graphs. Adding a comparison set would add a second line on each graph - this second line could be dotted or dashed to show the difference.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you consider side by side display, with visual indicators of difference?

If you can elaborate what's important (change/discrepancies, seeing whether values are higher or lower, etc.), that would be helpful, but if I was to implement something based on the limited information provided, I would consider displaying the two tables side by side (assuming this is possible, example indicates four columns which isn't too much data overhead). The first table would be the "reference", whereas the second table's cells would be marked to indicate differences from the first (perhaps colored red for lower values and green for higher?) like so:

[image: Example of two tables, side by side, with cells colored to indicate differences.]

You may like to pair this with an easy method to swap companies, as well as some sort of primitive 'query builder' to allow users to only select columns that matter so as not to overwhelm them with information.

If using colors, you could also adjust the saturation of the cell coloration to correspond with how great the difference in value is.

This idea may or may not be appropriate depending on how your data is structured. If you choose this idea, you may need to adjust your colors to suit the visually impaired.

**-Edit-**

Based on Andrew Martin's comment regarding the visually impaired, you could consider a similar implementation of this idea, such as using small arrow icons in the cells to indicate differences instead of color. 
Furthermore, as per his comment, these "difference indicators" may require a sentence clarifying their meaning, may convey unintended meaning to those unfamiliar with the interface, and may not be appropriate for every column/row.

Comment: Using colour alone is bad for accessibility - especially with red/green indicators: people with deuteranopia cannot distinguish the difference.

Comment: Already noted at bottom of post and it depends on the scenario. The reality is that an internal tool for a select few managers to refer to will have a different set of requirements to a public-facing tool used by millions, and either scenario may not rule out the use of color when it comes to what OP/their employers value.

Comment: No, it doesn't depend on the scenario. Using colour alone is bad for accessibility. Deuteranopes are not the only people you need to worry about. using colour under text reduces legibility. Cognitive issues also creep in: does red mean down or bad? Up can also be bad. Does green mean it's just OK or that there's progress? Even if this is for a small number of users you cannot guarantee the abilities of the users and you cannot guarantee that those abilities will not change over time.

Comment: Speaking from a business perspective as it sounds like this is business related: If a company does not employ a deuteranope, then the visibility concerns of deuteranopes w.r.t internal software may not be relevant. This is a hypothetical scenario where deuteranopes are not a priority.

Often, the needs of a minority do not map perfectly onto the needs of a corporate entity. Many changes could be made to improve many things in life, yet are not made due to a plethora of reasons. All that said, I intentionally did not omit mentioning the visually impaired.

Comment: Moving beyond deuteranopes, obviously red/green coloration isn't a silver bullet and can be confusing, hence why it was suggested in parenthesis.

Your concerns are why I attempted to be suitably vague in my proposal. The OP needs to consider their application before deciding what/whether coloration is appropriate for their needs. That said, the problems you mention aren't deal-breakers; they could be addressed with a simple blurb of text. It's intellectually dishonest to discount color as an option for the OP just because there are caveats to using it.

Comment: That said, I have appended a note with respect to your concerns to my suggestion.

Comment: My concerns were not about the vagueness in your answer. My concerns were that you were offering a solution that is actively damaging to accessibility. Accessibility is always a concern unless you are building for a single user. Staff change and their needs change. You cannot predict what issues staff may or may not be experiencing at any time and, with modern legal requirements around staff hire, internal software has to be as accessible as public-facing software.

Comment: _"You can't predict what issues staff may or may not be experiencing..."_
Correct.

_"...with modern legal requirements around staff hire..."_
These vary with region.

_"...internal software has to be as accessible as public software."_
It would be nice if this were true, but in some cases this would be seen as 'gold plating' software. I cannot speak for OP (their target market _could_ be those with perfect eyesight), so I settled for noting it at the base of my original post. As I have edited my post further to offer an alternative, non-color solution, I regard the matter resolved.

Comment: You may "regard this matter closed" but in 15 years of working with accessibility I have never come across a client who saw it as 'gold plating' and that's working in-house, as a contractor, and with agencies - what I am seeing now is that more and more briefs actually specify that a product MUST be accessible whether it's a public facing site or an internal tool.

Comment: I don't know where your 15 years of experience was, but a lot of public software that has been released without catering to the disabled is proof positive that the disabled are not a universal priority. I'm not endorsing the status-quo, but we can infer that limitations exist as a result. May I also suggest that by "working with accessibility", it is possible that you have experienced a form of confirmation bias by effectively being immersed in a culture that already valued/championed accessibility?

Comment: Regardless, I have recognized that your point was valid and have updated my post accordingly to credit you and acknowledge your point. If you could propose a superior solution for the OP's scenario, that would be excellent material for another answer, but differences in how we perceive the world to be is beyond the scope of the comments section for this question.

Comment: I am not discussing differences in how we perceive the world but am trying desperately to help you understand that the answer you proposed is, at it's core, bad for accessibility which should be considered in *all* cases. As for my answer, you will note from the comments at the top of the page that I requested further information and made a tentative suggestion there.

Comment: Adding my 2 cents: This solution would work well only for small tables due to the high demand of pixels that bigger tables would require.

Answer (score 1):

Some data fun from Edward Tufte: the **cancer death rates**.

[image]

What can we see from here?

- Tufte knows a thing or two about fun examples
- The dynamics of death rate over the years.

How can we apply it to our example? Literally:

[image]
*European revenue in billions of dollars of a fictional company. The company's CEO successfully used this data visualization to prove he's worth his business jet.*

In our case, the graphs are even more illustrative. While Tufte's patients are all dying, our regions can both emerge and fall. And we'll see it instantly.

Comment: +1 For the reference to Edward Tufte and the application of his concepts to this problem!

Comment: Thank you for taking time write your wonderful comment. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can the data be merged into one table and presented like this? This saves the user from having to jump back and forth between two tables, and might be easier to use on smaller viewports.

[image: Chart with A/B comparisons in one table]